# How do I get Table adapters to Delete rows from the database?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I have SQL code in a Table Adapter that contains a Join. This information gets populated into the corresponding Datatable when run. That part works fine. When I attempt to delete information from the database using the tableadapter.delete command or marking the rows for deletion than using the .update command I get errors. The update produces and error that states there is problem before the word JOIN. and the Delete statement says the same. The delete statement previously worked when there was not a join involved during testing. Is it not possible to use table adapters to delete information from the database using Joins?

Original table adapter code that fills the Datatable

```
  `SELECT * FROM SCRAP S
   JOIN SCRAP_TYPE T on T. SCRAP_TYPE_ID = S.SCRAP_TYPE_ID`
```

Query that populates data based on conditions for that Datatable

```
`SELECT * FROM SCRAP S
 JOIN SCRAP_TYPE T on T. SCRAP_TYPE_ID = S.SCRAP_TYPE_ID
 WHERE SCRAP_DATE BETWEEN @DATEFROM AND @DATETO
 AND T.CODE = @CODE`
```

This code is from the Delete.commandtext in the properties window

```
`DELETE FROM SCRAP 
 JOIN SCRAP_TYPE  ON SCRAP_TYPE.SCRAP_TYPE_ID = SCRAP.SCRAP_TYPE_ID
 WHERE SCRAP.SCRAP_DATE BETWEEN @DATEFROM AND @DATETO
 AND SCRAP_TYPE.CODE = @CODE`
```

I have not added sql to the insert or update commands. but when I run the code below I just get a syntax error before the word JOIN

```
    `foreach (DataRow row in Main.dScrap.Rows)
            {
                row.Delete();
            }

            dScrapTableAdapter.Update(Main.dScrap);`
```

Comment: Are you using a Command Builder? ( see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder?view=netframework-4.8).  An Adapter has 4 commands 1) Select 2) Update 3) Insert 4) Delete.  The adapter needs all 4 commands to work properly.  The command builder takes the Select command and automatically build the other three commands.

Comment: Can you post some code snippets? Also provide the area where the code was failing?

Comment: I was not aware it needed all four to work, that is probably my problem.

Comment: @jdweng I am using the DataSet Desginer.

Comment: The command builder takes an adapter as the parameter so if you have an adapter the command builder should work.  The commands are inside the adapter and need to get updated.